# selecting records with field varchar size restricted

Tags: sql, oracle

it is possible to do a select that brings a string column with a restricted number of characters? For example, I have a column that has records with 10 and 15 characters, I want only has 10 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm). Tested example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9b800/1

```
create table t (v varchar(50));

insert into t values ('this is a test of the substr fn');
insert into t values ('this is another test of the substr fn');

select 
  substr(v,1,10) restricted_output, 
  v unrestricted_output
from t
```

Resultset:

```
RESTRICTED_OUTPUT    UNRESTRICTED_OUTPUT
this is a            this is a test of the substr fn
this is an           this is another test of the substr fn
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a big vague.  Are you saying a field in a table allows X characters (15,30, whatever) and you only want those records with a Length of 10?  if so... the following would work substituting table name and yourField for the values in your system.

```
Select * from tableName where length(yourField) = 10
```

If however you're after all table columns having a length of 10.  Look at All_tab_cols view for a list of table/columns and field sizes.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted. Obs: in my sqldbx function is len(). Thanks!